# Storyboard controller initialisation, where can I place pre-init code?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

so I have a simple application using a storyboard. I have a few view controllers linked by segues. I also have one controller set as the default "first view controller". I understand that no code is required for the app to automatically load this was the first controller. However I want the app to first run a few checks (i.e. is the user logged in) before it decides which controller to push. Is there anywhere I should be putting this code or should I remove the "first view controller" setting on the storyboard and init manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the LoginViewcontroller as initial viewcontroller and if the user is logged in change the initial viewcontroller to something  else, you can change the initial view controller by changing the rootViewController property of the window

Answer (score 1):

I would leave your first controller as is, and check in AppDelegate if you want to show Login screens. If you do show them push that controller, otherwise, show your "first view controller".

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but when using a story board the AppDelegate automatically pushes the first controller regardless as it isn't coded in.

Comment: Yes but you push over that controller. The problem with starting with Login Storyboard is because you will use it only sometimes but "first view controller" will be used almost always.
With self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: you can achieve that.
Good luck :)

Comment: oh so If I do a user check and if the user is already logged in, pushing a controller will automatically override that?

Comment: If the user is logged you will not execute this at all; if you want to show login screen to user do the command above and it will show it. I have code for dismiss as well if you need it :)

Comment: I actually created another blank view controller, it's set to the initial controller and in the viewDidAppear method I have an if function to decide if to push the login controller or the friends controller. seems to work fine. is this an okay way to do it?

Comment: You can do it like that as well, but it will consume more memory. It's not the optimal solution.